# Why do I get "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error?

Tags: python

level: beginner

Why do I get "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error?

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transaction.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    new_price = cell.value * 0.9
    new_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    new_price_cell.value = new_price

wb.save('transaction1.xlsx')
```

I am importing the transaction.xlsx file.

[sample input of transaction file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiqkD.png)

Comment: give the sample input from transaction.xlsx file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the values in the `price` column contain the `$` symbol, which means that all the values in that column are `strings`. In order to convert them into `floats`, just remove that `$` symbol using the `.replace` method and `type cast` them into `floats`. This is how you do it:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    new_price = cell.value
    new_price = float(new_price.replace("$","")) * 0.9
    new_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    new_price_cell.value = new_price
```